# Bash - Find - move files bigger than certain size

Tags: bash, shell-script, filesystems, find, mv

How can I move all files bigger than lets say 10MB into a different folder?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 nath nath 4,3M Apr 21  2018 "file1.mp3"
-rw-r--r-- 1 nath nath 1,7M Jun 10  2017 'file2.mp3'
-rw-r--r-- 1 nath nath  76M Okt 12 05:33  file3.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 nath nath 3,7M Mär  1  2016 'file4.mp3'
```

so in this case it would only move `file3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok 5 minutes after posting the question I found the answer:

```
find . -type f -size +10M -exec mv "{}" new_folder/ \;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering your own question.  Be weary that on certain versions of `find` this command will not work as expected.  It may not even fail but instead may just move all files regardless of size.

Comment: wary means cautious; weary means tired.