# Operate on all files under a folder that are larger than some size

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, search

I'm working with some PhotoRec output files, and I'm only interested in files that are larger than a certain size threshold let's say 10M. I've found ways to sort recursively in other posts ([Sorting files according to size recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88065/sorting-files-according-to-size-recursively)) but I couldn't quite figure out let's say move all of these files to a different location.

Right now the structure of the folders looks something like this:

---

parent folder

- re1
- re2
- re...

Comment: See also related posts: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484791/bash-find-move-files-bigger-than-certain-size and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310085/how-do-i-move-files-based-on-size I will mark it as a duplicate but I have also added an answer to do this with one `mv` process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` command, to find and move all files with size more than 10M.

```bsh
find . -type f -size +10M -exec mv -t path/to/target/dir {} +
```

Using this syntax, we use ony one `mv` process for all the files, or better to say, only as many processes as necessary, as in case of too many arguments, this is handled internally and a second, third etc process could be raised, if needed.

When it can be used, that means where we can execute the command with multiple arguments, it is better from the syntax `-exec <command> {} \;` where one process per argument is raised. The important thing to use `{} +` is that nothing can exist between the curly braces and the `+`, so for the `mv` command we have to use the `-t` parameter to define the target directory.